# Is it possible to solve this equation symbolicaly with Mathematica/Mupad?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving, symbolic-computation

I am trying to solve equation symoblicaly with Mupad, where on the left side I have differential of $p_3$, and on the right side I also have normal value of $p_3$ (not differential).

```
o := ode(p3'(z) = (-diff(p1,z)*p2-diff(p2,z)*p1-8*diff(p2,z)-8*diff(p1,z)/p0+8*p1*diff(p0,z)/p0^2-diff(p0,z)*p3(z))/p0,p3(z))
```

On the other side variables $p_0$,$p_1$,$p_2$ are:

```
  p0:=sqrt(1+64*(1-z))
  p1:=8*(1/sqrt(1+64*(1-z))-1)
  p2:=(-ln(sqrt(1+64*(1-z)))+4*(1-1/(1+64*(1-z))))/sqrt((1+64*(1-z)))
```

When I gave command

```
solve(o)
```

to Mupad, I have got some integral which is not solved, it is not final result. How can I do this with Mupad, and is it possible so solve it symbolicaly on this way? Or is it Wolfram Mathematica better and would it solve it, or there is some other problem?

Equations:
$$p_0=(1+64\cdot(1-z))^{0.5}$$
$$p_1=8 \cdot(\dfrac{1}{p_0}-1)=8 \cdot(\dfrac{1}{(1+64\cdot(1-z))^{0.5}}-1)$$
$$p_2=\dfrac{8}{p_0}(-ln(p_0)+4\cdot(1-\dfrac{1}{p_0^2}))$$
$$p_2=\dfrac{8}{(1+64\cdot(1-z))^{0.5}}(-ln((1+64\cdot(1-z))^{0.5})+4\cdot(1-\dfrac{1}{(1+64\cdot(1-z))}))$$

Differential equation which I am solving here:
$$p_3'=\dfrac{-p_1'p_2-p_1p_2'-8p_2'-8\dfrac{p_1'}{p_0}+8\dfrac{p_1p_0'}{p_0^2}-p_0'p_3}{p_0}$$

or in other form:

$$\dfrac{dp_3}{dz}=\dfrac{-\dfrac{dp_1}{dz}p_2-p_1\dfrac{dp_2}{dz}-8\dfrac{dp_2}{dz}-8\dfrac{\dfrac{dp_1}{dz}}{p_0}+8\dfrac{p_1\dfrac{dp_0}{dz}}{p_0^2}-\dfrac{dp_0}{dz}p_3}{p_0}$$

Comment: Can you write out the question as a math problem with the respective equations?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I converted the equations to Mathematica correctly,

$
   \text{p3}(z)=\frac{c_1 (65-64 z)^2+64 (65-64 z)^{3/2}+96 (64 z-65)+4 (65-64
    z) \log (65-64 z)+32}{(65-64 z)^{5/2}}
$

Comment: Can you tell me please which code did you implement to do this? Because I am trying with DSolve, but it is not giving me results, it is staying in form of my command?

Comment: https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/STACK/bc-mupad.m

Comment: Why do you have z_ in parenthesis in equation for p0,p1 and p2, and after that there is only z in DSolve?

Comment: I've updated the code to make it clearer. For p0 through p2, I am defining functions so using `z_`. For p3, I am stating an equality, so only use `z`, not `z_`.